Principal Component Analysis and Information Gain for feature selection
I am currently undergoing a project for credit risk assessments with a dataset with 24 features and over 1 million lines. I have performed all the necessary exploratory data analysis and pre-processing steps. After I have performed the tuning of parameters to find the best combination and fitted the best classifier in the whole dataset.
My idea would be to test this pipeline over different models (Logistic Regression, Tree based algorithms, etc.) and in the end try out ensemble based approaches. My pipeline looks something like this:
pipeline_dt = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessing_pipeline),
    ("pca", pca),
    ("selector", selector),
    ("model", model)
])

I have noticed that the model do take quite some time to train and would like to exclude some of the features contained in the dataset. I have looked at different forms of feature extraction and wanted to try Information Gain and PCA but from what I have been reading I have trouble understanding if this could work as an approach. My questions are:

Should feature selection be performed or after PCA?

Does it make sense to use both PCA and Information Gain together? I can see based on the analysis of the PCS i can see some relationships like PC1 represents financial characteristics and PC2 financial capacity and transaction history. However these only account for 30% of the total variance. I understand feature extraction should be performed on the original features and not on principal components. I am trying to strike a balance between interpretability and predictive performance.


Thank you!
